# Is there way for force a browser to load swf files before other elements in the page

Tags: flash, http

Is there way to get the browser to always load any swf files before everything else on a page (exept the external css and swfobject.js). Using Firebug's Net statistics I can see the swf files generally load last.

We have all our external js files inserted at the bottom of the page to help loading times.

If this is a little vague then I'm more than happy to answer any questions.

Many thanks

Comment: Is the goal to slow down your page rendering speed? Is it too fast?

Comment: Hi Justice, the goal is just to load the swf file first, before say the images. 

To be honest Justice the site we built implements the clients bespoke advertising system which seems to load their ads before everything else and it was that I was trying get to get to load last but I thought I would ask this question as I was interested to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's up to the browser to load what it feels is necessary and in what order.

You've taken the first step; that is moving content to the bottom to load at a later point, however the saving wouldn't be detrimental.

Try using something like HTTP compression (gzip or [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html) for example), to increase the speed in which the user receives data to reduce the overall load time, as opposed to trying to load certain elements.

Comment: Thanks Shadow. I kind of guess that was the case as I searched around before posting here and I came up with nothing.